# Whats the run time complexity of this function?

Tags: c, algorithm, runtime, complexity-theory

```
void fn(int n){

    int p,q;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        p=0;
        for(int j=n;j>1;j=j/2)
            ++p;
        for(int k=1;k<p;k=k*2)
            ++q;

    }

}
```

1. I think its complexity is nlogn
2. My friend says its nlog(logn)

and also please tell me - Do inner loops depend upon each other in this function?

Comment: We are not a "do my homework" site.

Answer (score 5):

It's actually of undefined complexity because you use q uninitialised.

Ignoring that small bug, the outer loop is obviously `O(n)`. The first inner loop is `O(log n)`. The second inner loop is `O(log p)` and `p` is `log n` so it's `O(log log n)` but it doesn't matter because it is executed sequentially after the first inner loop and therefore the total for both inner loops is `O(log n)` (When you add two complexities, the overall complexity is the fastest growing one). So your overall complexity is `O(n log n)`